# Dictionary of Pandas' Dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

As the question asks I have a dictionary of pandas' `dataframes` that I want to save so that I don't have to resample the data next time I start the `ipython` notebook. I tried something simple which has worked in other cases before:

```
import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

But I got this error:

```
[1001 rows x 6 columns] is not JSON serializable
```

I think this has something to do with my pandas `dataframe`, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why not use a HDFStore?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to extend the JSON encoder so it knows how to serialise a dataframe.
Example (using `to_json` method):

```
import json
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'to_json'):
            return obj.to_json(orient='records')
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Saving:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump({'1':df,'2':df}, fp, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

Now if you will do

```
json.load(open('result.json')
```

You will get a dictionary with your dataframes. You can load them using

```
pd.read_json(json.load(open('result.json'))['1'])
```

Comment: Using the pandas `to_json` function returns a string, which will will be formatted as an escaped string when dumping to the json file.  Instead use `to_dict` with `orient='records'` to create a valid json object.

Answer (score 11):

While the above works, the serialized dataframes go into json as embedded strings.  If you want pretty json, first convert dataframes into dictionaries, then write using normal json interface.  You would convert back to dataframes after reading from disk:

```py
# data is dictionary of dataframes

import json

# convert dataframes into dictionaries
data_dict = {
    key: data[key].to_dict(orient='records') 
    for key in data.keys()
}

# write to disk
with open('data_dict.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(
        data_dict, 
        fp, 
        indent=4, 
        sort_keys=True
    )

# read from disk
with open('data_dict.json', 'r') as fp:
    data_dict = json.load(fp)

# convert dictionaries into dataframes
data = {
    key: pd.DataFrame(data_dict[key]) 
    for key in data_dict
}
```

Comment: If dataframe has TimeStamp objects, it will give error like `TypeError: Object of type Timestamp is not JSON serializable`