# python dict to json conversion pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have [dictionay of dictionaries](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IvH133BgD-p5FzcPifl92C1kXOoZTFac/view) ,when I am trying to dump it into a json using:

```
js = json.dumps(results, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
with open('output.json', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(js)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

I tried all the available solutions but they didn't work out for me.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a dict of dict. but a dict of Dataframe

Comment: can you post your code before you do json dumps ? can you explain how you get to the `results` ?

Comment: @arzo if you observe closely,the larger dict contains keys whose values may be a dataframe.

Comment: @yAzou sorry, I think that won't be possible as there are too many modules involved.

Comment: Yes values are Dataframe, so this is dictionnary of Dataframe. if value were also dict here you would have a dict of dict. How to you build `result` ? edit your post and share this code

Comment: try json.dump instead of .dumps

Comment: @bikoman57 That's the exact same, just the version passing the file, that does 100% the same

Comment: Did you try `pd.to_json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some values in the dict that have type `pandas.DataFrame`.

You may try extending the JSON encoder as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33062932/727089).

Answer (score -1):

I read your question. I would suggest that you check the type of 'results' by using the type function

```
type(results)
```

I ran a dummy code using a dictionary of dictionaries on my PC and I found the above code working.
Do check that each object in `results` dictionary is of type `dict` i.e. dictionary.

Comment: it's dictionary

Comment: Try checking each object in the 'results' dictionary