# pandas read_json with orient="table"

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have dumped a dict of dataframes expanding the json encoder based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061302/dictionary-of-pandas-dataframe-to-json#answer-33062932). I just altered the way to dump the dataframe, changing orient="records" to orient="table" for my own purpose.

Somehow I can't manage to read the dataframes from the json ; to be precise, pandas seems to read it allright (no exception is raised), but it is filled with NaN values.

Can anybody check if I'm doing anything wrong or if this is a bug for pandas (maybe referring to multiindexed dataframes) ?

I'm using pandas version 1.1.4.

The following code would be enough (I hope) to either test if pandas is KO on my machine or if I've somehow messed up with the dataframe's format. I've also tried to reproduce this with a dummy dataframe including two indexes and didn't run into trouble.

Note also that the json displays a "pandas_version": "0.20.0" which is incoherent with my version (I just made a fresh installation to be sure and it stays there). I've seen the same 0.20.0 version is displayed on [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html?highlight=to_json#pandas.DataFrame.to_json)'s example for current pandas version...

```
import pandas as pd
s = """{
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
                "name": "grandeur",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "unite",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "year",
                "type": "integer"
            }, {
                "name": 1,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 2,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 3,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 4,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 5,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 6,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 7,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 8,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 9,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 10,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 11,
                "type": "number"
            }, {
                "name": 12,
                "type": "number"
            }
        ],
        "primaryKey": ["grandeur", "unite", "year"],
        "pandas_version": "0.20.0"
    },
    "data": [{
            "grandeur": "Volumetric soil water layer 1",
            "unite": "m3 m-3",
            "year": 1981,
            "1": 0.3893150916,
            "2": 0.3614713229,
            "3": 0.3965121538,
            "4": 0.3513062306,
            "5": 0.3860211495,
            "6": 0.3507631742,
            "7": 0.3499931922,
            "8": 0.3195245205,
            "9": 0.3078848032,
            "10": 0.3917079828,
            "11": 0.380486904,
            "12": 0.3987094194
        }, {
            "grandeur": "Volumetric soil water layer 1",
            "unite": "m3 m-3",
            "year": 1982,
            "1": 0.3924450997,
            "2": 0.360954089,
            "3": 0.3714920435,
            "4": 0.3366828332,
            "5": 0.329994006,
            "6": 0.3659116305,
            "7": 0.3035419171,
            "8": 0.3143600073,
            "9": 0.3099404359,
            "10": 0.3938543858,
            "11": 0.383870834,
            "12": 0.3909665621
        }]
}"""
pd.read_json(s, orient="table")
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with all these spaces and \n  in s? Were they created when you dumped the dict or you added them to beutify s?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I don't think so. I just parsed it to make it easier to read on SO and also smaller (there are more rows than this). It was at first a one liner including escapes for all quotes.

Comment: It is due to `"name": 1` in schema is integer and data's key has string "1".  
You can test by changing to `"name": "1"` in schema to see value in 1 appears.

Comment: @Emma I'm not so sure about that. "1" is the label for the column (stands for january actually) ; you can see the values in the "data" section of the json, and those are definitely floats...

Comment: Right the issue I am talking about is the schema not data part. 
This could be the pandas limitation that integer column name would face issues when storing schema and data information at `to_json`.  However I just modified `{ "name": "1", "type": "number" }` in schema, the values in column 1 appears.

Comment: @Emma Indeed... Please post your answer so that I could validate it. I'll try to submit an issue on pandas, this is no normal behaviour !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a field in schema is not matching a key in data.

For example,

schema

```
{
    "name": 1,   // integer
    "type": "number"
}
```

data

```
"1": 0.3893150916  // "1" is string
```

====================================================

If you change schema to match with data key. `read_json` should read properly.

schema

```
{
    "name": "1",   // string
    "type": "number"
}
```

data

```
"1": 0.3893150916  // "1" is string
```

If the example json string is generated by pandas `to_json`, it is generating a wrong schema for integer column name.

Comment: In fact, the schema is right, that's the data which is wrong and displaying (what should be integers as) strings. I've submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38256). (As a complement : those integer labels for columns may seem awkward, but those are the results of a "melt" method, so nothing unusual here...)

Comment: I just read the issue thread.  JSON doesn't allow integer key so with this format, I agree it makes sense not to allow integer column name or convert the column name into string.

Comment: I'd personnally go for the warning option with casting the integer to string (but that's not up to me). I'm a bit lost as to why my first example (here in SO) returned an empty dataframe though the minimal example I put on Github raises an exception...