# JSON to DataFrame conversion

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Is pd.json_normalize() and pd.DataFrame.from_dict() same and produce similar results?
I am using this to create a dataframe from a JSON Dictionary. Please help

Comment: Why not try both and see the results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061302/dictionary-of-pandas-dataframe-to-json